# Gradient and leaf score for the first tree of XGBoost

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, xgboost

So, when deriving the first tree in xgboost, we need to know the first order and second order gradients, p-y and p(1-p) to calculate the leaf weights and overall tree score. But since we do not have any tree yet, how do we get p for each sample ?.

Is this the base_score or prior ?

Is there a mathematical derivation which proves what is the best such value ? Specially when we consider regression against classification.

Is there any option to specify a prior probability array for all samples of a population ? That is not a default 0.5 for all samples - but based on some prior distribution ?

Thanks